# Actions on Google Smart Home

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

i wrote a smart home skill for Alexa, which interacts with a bunch of REST apis i created. It integrated with my OAUTH2 server, all good.

I've tried reading the limited Actions on Google documentation, and looked at the example Node app on github, and i'm stumped. 
The action.json seems to take a single URL - i'm unclear on what that should be, the example takes the easy route of passing a single url, then deciding on sync/execute etc as url param in the index.js, which I don't want to do. 
Can someone please explain how this works for them? I see a bunch of other people struggling on here, so i take some comfort that i may be thick, but i'm not alone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you developed an Alexa smart home skill, you should know the skill adapter hosted as a Lambda function.
The example Node.js program works just like the skill adapter.

When Google Home invokes your smart home app, it sends the request to the url in the action.json. You can use the example Node.js app for this url, then write your function to handle sync/execute requests. This part should be very similar to the REST APIs you created for Alexa.

Comment: thanks Chris - i was expecting some different behaviours obvs - so the google home action expects a single route which will then handle any invocation, and i go from there?

Comment: Yes, in the example Node app  smart-home-provider / smart-home-app.js, there is a app.post('/ha', function (request, response). Everything starts here. Then switch (intent), action.devices.SYNC is similar to Alexa's Alexa.ConnectedHome.Discovery, action.devices.EXECUTE is similar to Alexa's Alexa.ConnectedHome.Control.